# 404 (Not Found) error using .ts files

Tags: angular, typescript

when I load a page on my production env., I get the following error:

> GET http://example.com/Scripts/main.ts 404 (Not Found) error:
>   (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://example.com/Scripts/main.ts

This **does not happen** on my dev. env.

This happens in my index.html file. I verified and all paths are correct, and the `main.ts` file exists in the path.

```
<script src="/Scripts/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
      System.import('/Scripts/main.ts').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

If I change my `main.ts` file to `main.js` extention, there's **no** 404 error.

Here is my systemjs.config.js file:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
    map: {
      app: 'app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs@5.0.1',
      'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript@5.2.7/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript':                'npm:typescript@2.0.10/lib/typescript.js',

    },

    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
        main: '/Scripts/main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });

})(this);
```

Comment: Please see the answer that I posted below. The answer you accepted was written in conplete ignorance of modern JavaScript tools transpilers, workflows, and build systems. It would be a shame to see it as the accepted answer since it is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser doesn't understand TypeScript, only the TypeScript compiler does. The output of the TypeScript compiler is JavaScript, so `main.js` is the correct file to import.

Comment: I can't change all files to JS... This doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not telling you to change your files to JS. I'm telling you to not include the TypeScript files in the browser. Here's an analogy: If you write Java code, it gets compiled to bytecode, which gets executed by the Java runtime. No Java runtime knows what to do with a .java source file, they only work with bytecode. Similarly, your browser doesn't understand TypeScript. You code in TypeScript, compile to JavaScript and use the JavaScript file in the browser. That's the only way it works.

Comment: How do I accomplish that ? And how does it work on my dev env ?

Comment: That's hard to say, because you already have compiled .js files. There must already be something that calls the TypeScript compiler. Maybe Angular CLI? Some Gulp or Grunt configuration? If that's working, you should simply change your imports to use the .js file instead. It's functionally equivalent to the .ts file.

Comment: Sine you latest comment I searched for any additional .JS file that might have been created - but there are no additional JS files. I don't have any client running, not Gulp or Grunt. Nothing...

Comment: Okay, run `tsc.exe --watch` to create your .js files. And check `tsconfig.json` for the `outdir`, which is where they will be placed. If that doesn't help, I suggest you create a plunkr that shows your setup. I should be able to fix it up.

Comment: So what you suggest is compiling all my ts files to js files, to some directory, and refer my pages to use them, and not the ts files ?

Comment: That's it, yes. If you are in the early stages of your project, I would suggest looking into using Angular CLI. It does everything for you, with no configuration required (some configuration possible, but not required).

Comment: So now that I've compiles all ts files to .js files (in the same locations), where do I change my code to use them, and not the ts files, so the browser can point to them ?

Comment: `System.import('/Scripts/main.ts')` and similar statements should simply refer to the .js. And any `<script>` tags as well.

Comment: I'm not using import with file extensions. I changed the defaultExtension: 'ts' to: defaultExtension: 'ts', now I get various error messages. Is that the right thing to do ?

Comment: defaultExtensoin in which file? Perhaps you should work through the Angular Quickstart first. It feels like you're trying to learn TypeScript in the comment section, and that's not going to work.

Comment: I've been throught several tutorials, but you're right.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I mentioned it before, but let me say it again: Try Angular CLI. It works out of the box, uses best practices and has a large community that can answer your questions.

Comment: Wanted to let you know that I managed to run it now perfectly, just had to change a few things in my tsconfig.json and just change main.ts to main.js. Thanks for your patience and your help. Peace and love from Israel.

Comment: This seriously wrong, and written in complete ignorance of your tool chain which is simply misconfigured. @CobusKruger, did you even bother to read the question? Don't answer questions you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay no heed to @Cobus Kruger's answer, he is terribly uninfomed.

It is perfectly valid to import TypeScript files directly in the browser during development (or bundle them dynamically) just the way you are trying to do it. There's absolutely no need to run gulp tasks or anything of the sort to compile your TypeScript either for development or for a production bundle.

You just have a few minor configuration errors.

Note the updated config below. I put extra blank lines around the changes

```
function (global) {
  System.config({

    defaultJSExtensions: true,

    baseURL: "/",

    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "system",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
    map: {



      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs@5.0.1',
      'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript@5.2.7/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript':                'npm:typescript@2.0.10/lib/typescript.js',

    },

    packages: {

        // note the differences particularly here

      app: {

        // assuming Scripts is a subdir of app
        main: 'Scripts/main.ts',

        defaultExtension: 'ts',

        meta: {
          "*.ts": {
            loader: "ts"
          },

          "*.js": {
            loader: "ts"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

})(this);
```

Finally alter your in browser bootstrapping so that you have the following

```
<script src="/Scripts/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

No that we import from the app package that we can figured which will give us **main.ts**

Depending on where your **Scripts** folder is in relation to your **app** folder you may have to make a couple of changes but it was clearly coming from the wrong directory.

If you don't actually have a folder named **app** that contains **main.ts**, just change the name of your package in the `packages` property above from **app** to **Scripts** and then `System.import('Scripts')`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it Sunday and rate accordingly.

Comment: I just tested your solution, but it returns me to the same error I hade before: http://example.com/Scripts/main.ts 404 (Not Found) error.